# Inherit one class to another class in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have worked a lot with Xcode But, How to inherit one class to another class in Xcode.

Comment: Xcode is the IDE.  Your question (I assume) is actually about Objective-C and is very likely a duplicate.  Please search on SO or make your question more specific with some code you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about writing Objective C, you specify a superclass of your class in it's `@interface` declaration after a colon. If you're doing OS X or iOS development, every class you're using probably already inherits from something. For example, your app delegate interface probably looks like:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : UIResponder
```

In this case, `MyAppDelegate` is a subclass of `UIResponder`. Or, in the case of a view controller:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
```

Your `MyViewController` class is a subclass of `UIViewController`. Even a "do nothing" class that isn't directly integrated into the framework will still inherit from `NSObject` by convention.